# File size issue with PEAR Spreadsheet Excel Writer?

Tags: php, excel, pear

I have this code:

```
$book = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();
$book->send('book.xls');
$report =& $book->addWorksheet('sheet');

$i = 0; 
while ($i<145){
    $report->write($i, 0, 'dsbajk_'.$i);
    $i++;
}

$book->close();
```

This produces a file of 6 KB but when I tried to open it in Excel there is an error with the file, something like: Excel found content that couldn't read and is possible that some data was lost. (I can't write the exact message because is in Spanish).

If I change 145 to 144 (or less) in the loop no messages is displayed, so I think is a problem with the buffer or size of the text. I need to replace the while loop with a db query with more data so is important this works well.

I tried this in other server and I didn't have this problem, so maybe is something with the config.

I apreciate any help.

Comment: Don't use S_E_W. It's obsolete and basically unmaintained. Switch to [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) instead. That is maintained, and supports the new XML-based formats. S_E_W is stuck in Excel '95 or thereabouts.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB, I will give PHPExcel a chance. I was used to Spreadsheet Excel Writer, but you're right it is stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marc B said switch to PHPExcel is a good decision if you're starting a new project. It supports xlsx and other modern formats as well as the traditional xls. It also has more options and is easy to install and use.

I used PHPExcel in my project and I'm pretty happy. :)